# How to dynamically generate grids from a variety of templates

Tags: c#, wpf

I am relatively new to WPF and I'm trying to create a system where you can click a button to add a new tab which generates a corresponding grid to display content. For example, when you open a new tab, the first page would be "Home page", you then have options within this new tab to navigate to other content such as "Options". You can then add another tab and repeat the process etc. IT would be like Google Chrome how each tab represents another browser experience.

So far I have my tabs working, however I am stuck with how I am supposed to generate grids for each tab. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

- Create an abstract `TabData` base class with a `Header` `string` property.
- Create a class that derives from `TabData` for each type of tab that you want (e.g. HomeData, OptionsData, etc.)
- Create a view model with an `Items` property of type `IEnumerable<TabData>`.
- Bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `TabControl` to `Items` and define an implicit `DataTemplate` for each concrete `TabData` type:

  ```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <TabControl.Resources>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeData}">
              ...
          </DataTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OptionsData}">
              ...
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.Resources>
  </TabControl>
  ```

The `DataTemplate` defines the appearance of a tab and may contain a `DataGrid` or any other element.

Comment: sorry I should have clarified that I'm not using a tabs control. I'm using ListviewItems within a Listview to represent my tabs. The user can add and remove these tabs (listviewitems). Thanks for the answer and I'll see if I can adapt it